# Как создать ассоциативный массив из нескольких массивов?

Tags: javascript

Имеются массивы `a, b, c, d, e..` Необходимо создать новый массив `z`, состоящий из пар ключ значение: `a1 ->[b1, c1, d1, e1, ...]`, `a2->[b2, c2, d2, e2, ...]` Как сделать это более элегантно, без прогонки по цикл в JavaScript?

Comment: Без циклов здесь никак. Цикл в любом случае будет - явный `for` или не явный в каком-нибудь `map` или `reduce`.

Answer (score 6):

Если нельзя циклы, то можно, конечно, через рекурсию попробовать:

```js
const arrA = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5'];
const arrB = ['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5'];
const arrC = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5'];
const arrD = ['d1','d2','d3','d4','d5'];
const arrE = ['e1','e2','e3','e4','e5'];

const z = [];

function setNewArr(arrA,arrB,arrC,arrD,arrE) {
  const result = {};
  if(arrA.length == 0) {
    return z;
  }
  else {
    let firstA = arrA.shift();
    let newArr = [arrB.shift(), arrC.shift(), arrD.shift(), arrE.shift()];
    result[firstA] = newArr;
    z.push(result);
    return setNewArr(arrA,arrB,arrC,arrD,arrE);
  }
}
console.log(setNewArr(arrA,arrB,arrC,arrD,arrE));
```

Comment: Вариант отличный! Но к элегантности никакого отношения не имеет :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, ну, без циклов (явных и неявных) про элегантность можно забыть сразу :)

Comment: Согласен. Тут наверное надо ТС задать вопрос - он что хотел? Без циклов или элегантно :)

Answer (score 4):

Ну, если очень не хочется видеть слово *for*, можно поизвращаться:

```js
let a = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"];
let b = ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"];
let c = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"];
let d = ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"];
let e = ["e1", "e2", "e3", "e4"];

let obj = Object.fromEntries( a.map( (elem, i) => [ elem, [b[i], c[i], d[i], e[i]] ] ) );

console.log(obj);

/* a.map( (elem, i) => [ elem, [ b[i], c[i], d[i], e[i] ] ]
 * Заменяет каждый элемент из `a` на массив вида [элем, [......]]
 * Собирая в массив [...] элементы под номером `i` из остальных перечисленных массивов
 * На выходе: 
 *    [
 *      ["a1", ["b1", "c1", "d1", "e1"] ],
 *      ["a2", ["b2", "c2"... ] ],
 *    ]
 *
 * А Object.fromEntries() как-раз требует такой массив из подмассивов [ключ, значение]
 */
```

Но оно всё равно за кулисами делает свои циклы. И коротко != элегантно... я бы всё равно выбрал простой и понятный цикл, завернутый в функцию)

---

Исчо вариант, тоже по сути цикл, зато вызов прикольный:

```js
let a = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"];
let b = ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"];
let c = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"];
let d = ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"];
let e = ["e1", "e2", "e3", "e4"];

console.log( objKeys(a).values(b, c, d, e) );

/***/

function objKeys(arr){

  objKeys.values = function (...arrays){
    return arr.reduce( (obj, elem, i) => {
      obj[ elem ] = arrays.map( e => e[i] );
      return obj;
    }, {});
  }
  
  return objKeys;
}
```

Comment: Вот это вложенность.Можно хотя бы комментарии  написать к коду?

Comment: ну, a.map - это явный цикл, даже не за кулисами :)

Comment: @Demon __ Добавил комментарии. Я вот из-за этого и "за" классический цикл - чуть больше понятного кода, в который легче будет вникать. Чем делать в одну строчку, но потом при чтении разбирать несколько минут.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME спасибо (+1)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, `const matrix2obj = ([keys, ...q]) => Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k, i) => [k, q.map(q => q[i])]))`

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать проще, но я думаю читабельность у данного кода достаточна

```js
const arrA = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5'];
const arrB = ['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5'];
const arrC = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5'];
const arrD = ['d1','d2','d3','d4','d5'];
const arrE = ['e1','e2','e3','e4','e5'];

const arrs = [arrB, arrC, arrD, arrE];

var result = {};

arrA.forEach((e, i) => {
  result[e] = arrs.map(e => e[i]);
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ну forEach же - цикл. С циклом каждый может

Comment: @humster_spb вопрос в элегантности, map тоже цикл, и технически считать, рекурсивная функция предоставленная вами тоже является циклом

Comment: @ishidex2 более того - реурсивная функция хуже цилка по производительность\надежность.

Answer (score 0):

[там песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?alwaysStrict=false&allowUnusedLabels=true&ssl=9&ssc=6&pln=10&pc=46#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQQRgXhgbQORwIzYA0MuATESXAMwW4AstcArNgLoDcAUKJLIggCF0WbACMCxMeUmiaMhjJYdu4aPCQBhYTmASSwafrn6F%20pVx5r%20AEW3YAJnoeGHxh6YfmVvdQgCidgCmToEugW6BHoFeAPQxMAC0CZxxiclQAJ4ADoEwACQAtnBQCACWAB4APAAqAHzC1ZisTVypSZyZOflFJRWkRVnCABSYANaBGRDEAHSzAI6sAFzdxWVV0GVgAOa1AJTo9QCycFmVG6XbxOfbTbXeaj1r-SfLhat9A8NjE1Mws9MLfZoepgQIAdxgxyyQ3Gk2mAyGMOIpSB9TGxDm8JOQzmBxgc0wpVYu2JuxS8XanVyb165VIIFEACsvrDfv8Fq9HhUzr1tns8QBvLCjZbXLZLGBipowAC%2091gXLpDMZnPeSqZLJ%20M3mxLxAHkmYFgFBpgAzBAgAp%20MC9QIQGE-LHQpEwFF49H4p04vEEokk3ZktrJIPymAAGxAW2G7OWcDAGSaqJgQ0sIDDgWmEa2Q3Zu2IWbJlgVau0-GQxH4AgrmmrCGstb8hGUIaznBg7eT2EVzyyFG7CMVAbbHaGXbV9KZffHyqGg7JHZg7CAA)

```
const arrA = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'];
const arrB = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5'];
const arrC = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5'];
const arrD = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5'];
const arrE = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5'];
// --
// --
type $matrix<T> = T[][];
// --
type $matrix2map = ([keys, ...q]: $matrix<string>) => Map<string, string[]>
const matrix2map: $matrix2map = ([keys, ...q]) => new Map(keys.map((k, i) => [k, q.map(q => q[i])]))
// --
type $matrix2obj = ([keys, ...q]: $matrix<string>) => { [k: string]: string[] }
const matrix2obj: $matrix2obj = ([keys, ...q]) => Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k, i) => [k, q.map(q => q[i])]))
// --
// --
const log = (...q: any[]) => (console.log(...q), log)
const matrix = [arrA, arrB, arrC, arrD, arrE,];
// --
log
    ('matrix2map', matrix2map(matrix))
    ('matrix2obj', matrix2obj(matrix))
    ;
```

```js
const arrA = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'];
const arrB = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5'];
const arrC = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5'];
const arrD = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5'];
const arrE = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5'];
// --
// --
const matrix2map = ([keys, ...q]) => new Map(keys.map((k, i) => [k, q.map(q => q[i])]));
const matrix2obj = ([keys, ...q]) => Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k, i) => [k, q.map(q => q[i])]));
// --
// --
const log = (...q) => (console.log(...q), log);
const matrix = [arrA, arrB, arrC, arrD, arrE, ];
// --
log
  ('matrix2map', matrix2map(matrix)) // смотри консоль браузера
  ('matrix2obj', matrix2obj(matrix))
  ;
```