# Как создать Map с двумя Map внутри?

Tags: javascript

Вытаскиваю данные с биржи, сначала торговую пару, а потом к ней несколько данных по таймфреймам. То есть

```
pairs: {
    'EURUSD': {
        '30m': {rsi, sma, ohlc, ...}
        '1h':  {rsi, sma, ohlc, ...}
    }
}
```

Как это сделать?

```
if (!pairs.get(symbol)){
      pairs.set(symbol, ???)
    }
```

Как инициализировать содержимое двумя Map?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052132 - отметьте галочкой (слева от ответа) устраивающий Вас ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var symbol = 'EURUSD';
if (!pairs[symbol]) {
  pairs[symbol] = {
    '30m': {...},
    '1h':  {...}
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[там песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?alwaysStrict=false&allowUnusedLabels=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=66&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBHA7iJBvAUE-SEAHjAPYBOALkpQJ4zIAkcAluVAExggxIC8SABSt2ALiTMQbKAEp%20APgncYeAsTJUa9Jso4io-IcvGNlcvosnScq-OorUWwShHIAzBE33ZbBfAG0Aa3EoSnInAHMAXXFcP3iCIJCwyJiJABMQShBfPwBfXwLfe006BiUeQwBZHgAeUPDgCIAaCpgAIXlikgctctMeduq6hsjWxkzsru6NR2dXD0QMrMw4hKR2FnEQYFpm3IIobm3d-fWkUgALABt4E73CnALQSFhPVAwfPxLqeFJgUJIfRcHgmYHKQzeCw%20A74a4QajGD4gAB0A14AmAEDQSBqMEEMhs5zcFCE8OogQgtAAkkgnECpOw5GtznCEUgAG4ga60gT6IJU6lRWHxclIZTtcToVHooaY7G4ngEoms-Ak8hk9mU2gAKTpwE53OpzJF5zFkxAUowaIthi5PIFuuFqoSEpRUARgm1OtaFsJLqQRQDyndnu11NaEv96wK53ICIAruQDcpHs9wNA4EtpV81D1NH8AYieHpGVBRNK0booeLKtDcCLC4D9FaZTWsEH1iH1QBRBCXQSCCWtcPmRQs1n88NRQwd00EN29-uDi0jqk6se5gP4KeCqKOnUzgQW%20f4PLRhLnlUJeOUJMG-RpmwAFR7AGVn7FfGL2yKAOQ9gAqgASoBb4ACJ-l%20AZ-gAzAADGAUHYBsUBbEgwAJtc1ytEcloYVhOEXDcdwEdhrR5GcLp-gAjJcyFYKh6GYeRSB4eILFEVctwcYRFFUZejx%20E2xYYsiKLgkq%20gXkgIkMtIABi5CkGAeKGJW1ZlkOPAyU2pDwii1ykBEwhlkpKl4oSBRAA)

```
namespace qwa {
    export type $pairs2map = (pairs: $pairs) => $map
    export type $map2pairs = (map: $map) => $pairs

    export interface $pairs {
        [k: string]: {
            [k: string]: $data
        }
    }

    export type $map = Map<string, $mapB>
    export type $mapB = Map<string, $data>

    export interface $data {
        rsi: any,
        sma: any,
        ohlc: any,
    }
}
namespace qwa {
    export const pairs2map: $pairs2map = pairs => {

        let map: qwa.$map = new Map()

        for (let keyI in pairs) {
            let valI = pairs[keyI]
            let mapB: qwa.$mapB = new Map()

            for (let keyJ in valI) {
                let data: qwa.$data = valI[keyJ]
                mapB.set(keyJ, data)
            }

            map.set(keyI, mapB)
        }
        return map
    }
}
namespace qwa {
    export const map2pairs:qwa.$map2pairs = map => {

        const pairs: qwa.$pairs = {}

        map.forEach((mapB, keyI) => {
            pairs[keyI] = {}
            mapB.forEach((data, keyJ) => {
                pairs[keyI][keyJ] = data
            })
        })

        return pairs
    }
}

TEST: {
    let pairs = {
        'EURUSD': {
            '30m': { rsi: null, sma: null, ohlc: null, },
            '1h': { rsi: null, sma: null, ohlc: null, },
        }
    }
    const map = qwa.pairs2map(pairs)
    const pairsFromMap = qwa.map2pairs(map)
    console.log(pairsFromMap)
}
```

```js
var qwa;
(function (qwa) {
    qwa.pairs2map = pairs => {
        let map = new Map();
        for (let keyI in pairs) {
            let valI = pairs[keyI];
            let mapB = new Map();
            for (let keyJ in valI) {
                let data = valI[keyJ];
                mapB.set(keyJ, data);
            }
            map.set(keyI, mapB);
        }
        return map;
    };
})(qwa || (qwa = {}));
(function (qwa) {
    qwa.map2pairs = map => {
        const pairs = {};
        map.forEach((mapB, keyI) => {
            pairs[keyI] = {};
            mapB.forEach((data, keyJ) => {
                pairs[keyI][keyJ] = data;
            });
        });
        return pairs;
    };
})(qwa || (qwa = {}));
TEST: {
    let pairs = {
        'EURUSD': {
            '30m': { rsi: null, sma: null, ohlc: null, },
            '1h': { rsi: null, sma: null, ohlc: null, },
        }
    };
    const map = qwa.pairs2map(pairs);
    const pairsFromMap = qwa.map2pairs(map);
    console.log(pairsFromMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Map([
  [yourKeyA: new Map()], 
  [yourKeyB: new Map()], 
])
```

```js
const pairs  = new Map(), 
      symbol = 'EURUSD'; 

if (!pairs.has(symbol))
  pairs.set(symbol, new Map([
    ['30m', new Map()], ['1h', new Map()]
  ])); 

pairs.get('EURUSD').get('1h').set('rsi', { foo: 'bar' }); 

console.log(`pairs['EURUSD']['1h']['rsi'] is`, 
  pairs.get('EURUSD').get('1h').get('rsi')
);
```